# How to replace the removed Protected virtual DoTyping method from TCustomEdit?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a custom FMX combobox control I am trying to move from Delphi XE6 to Delphi 10.1 Berlin. The control inherits from TComboEdit. In my control, I override the protected virtual method - "DoTyping", that once existed in TCustomEdit, but no longer does in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. How do I keep my code without having to rewrite the entire control? Is there something synonymous in Delphi 10.1 Berlin that I am overseeing?

It looks as if TCustomEdit has added a new property

```
 Model: TCustomEditModel
```

Comment: Given that FMX now supports styled and native controls, you might have to redesign your component anyway to adapt this change. Perhaps you can get away by hijacking the OnTyping event, but I guess you will soon run into other problems when your control is somewhat more complex.

Comment: Hi UWE, can you give me some additional info on how I might go about hijacking the OnTyping event - thank you

Comment: Just wire the event to a method in your class. Be aware that a user can do the same bypassing your code.

Comment: Again, I do not understand this - sorry.   So, I have all this code in the DoTyping event (which the event no longer exists). I need to move that code elsewhere. You are saying that I "wire the event to a method in my class"??? So, I wire OnTyping to a method. This method would hold all my code from DoTyping method? how do you wire the event to the method?  thanks

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong here, but I assumed that someone able to write a custom component actually knows what "wire the OnTyping event" means. Sorry about that. So, TComboEdit has an event OnTyping. Usually you wire an event by double clicking in the Object Inspector and write the code in the newly created event handler method. You can as well have a method of your custom class with a parameter Sender: TObject that you assign to the classes OnTyping event in the constructor of that class. The space and formatting is somewhat limited here, so I cannot show the code.

Comment: @John: DoTyping is not an event, it is a virtual method that calls the OnTyping event when that is assigned. That method has been moved to the Model. See my comment to Johan's answer. Components are now separated into Control, Model and Presentation, so the presentation can either be a styled control or a native one. Only the code for the presentation must be replaced, the code for model and control can remain the same, It makes sense to make that separation in your controls too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could not be easier.

The stock TComboEdit has a `OnTyping` event.
Wherever the `DoTyping` method has moved to it's a sure bet its implementation looks like this:

```
procedure TSomething.DoTyping;
begin
  if assigned(FOnTyping) then FOnTyping(Self);
end;
```

So just pick up the code that used to be in `DoTyping`, cut it.
Put your custom ComboEdit (or a stock `TComboEdit`) on the form, go to events in the object inspector, double click on `OnTyping` and paste the code in the event handler.

```
procedure TForm50.ComboEdit1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Paste here.
end;
```

This is what Uwe calls "wiring the event".

Comment: That is indeed possible, but not really desirable. A control should not use its own events,especially because if other code sets the event and your handler is removed. The DoTyping has been moved to the Model. I think one should redo the component to use the MVP (or CMP, as they call it) separation. See [Part 1](http://yaroslavbrovin.ru/new-approach-of-development-of-firemonkey-control-control-model-presentation-part-1-en/) and [Part 2](http://yaroslavbrovin.ru/new-approach-of-development-of-firemonkey-control-control-model-presentation-part-2-tedit-with-autocomplete-en/) of a nice explanation